# Sum values that date_diff function returns

Tags: php, datetime, datediff, dateinterval, array-sum

I need to sum all values that date_diff function returns.

I have tried using array_sum(), but I get 0 as a result (as it is empty). The result should be 14.

```
$sql = "SELECT start_date, end_date FROM events";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $row["start_date"];   
     $row["end_date"];
     $start = date_create($row["start_date"]);
     $end = date_create($row["end_date"]);
     $fin=date_add($end, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 days'));

     $diff=date_diff($start, $fin);
      echo $diff->format('%d days');

}
```

Code that I have provided works, but when I add array_sum() it constantly shows 0.

Comment: Please add the code showing how you use `array_sum()`

Comment: @catcon I have tried many ways. I usually get 0 as result (empty array).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a base `DateTime`, and add all `date_diff` to it. Then calculate the sum date diff by subtracting the original base datetime.

```
$base_time = new DateTime();
$time = clone $base_time;
// begin foreach loop
...
$diff=date_diff($start, $fin);
$time->add($diff);
...
// end foreach loop
$sum_of_diff = $time->diff($base_time);
```